# Creating symbolic links in PHP/IIS 8 when using the new Application Pool Identity feature

Tags: php, iis, symlink, pool

I'm running IIS 8, Server 2012.  I have a web application where the programmers want to create symbolic links.  Here is some sample code:

```
$target = 'symlink.php';
$link = 'symlink-link.php';

symlink($target, $link);
echo readlink($link);
```

I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  symlink(): Cannot create symlink, error code(1314) in E:\...\test.php on line 7
```

I've granted the "IIS APPPOOL\apppooluser"  NTFS modify permissions.
I've granted the user rights assignment to the same user of 'Create symbolic Links'.

I cannot get this application to create links.  Any suggestions?  Is it impossible using IIS APP POOLs?

Answer (score 4):

Try the answer as written in a [comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php#109607)

> On IIS (Internet Information Services), you need to set permissions to
>   allow the creation of symbolic links.
>
> Go to Local Security Policy -> Local Policies -> User Rights
>   Assignment and right click on Create symbolic links -> Properties ->
>   Add User or Group and add the "IUSR" user, which should be the user
>   associated with IIS. A restart may be required.
>
> If this doesn't work, go to IIS Manager -> Authentication -> select
>   Anonymous Authentication -> Edit and enter your current logged in
>   user, which should be an administrator. Hit OK and now the symlink()
>   function in php should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I have already granted the user rights assignment to the "IIS APPPOOL\apppooluser"


As far as the second suggestion, assigning the currently logged in user ('which should be an administrator') to be the account under which anonymous users run under (through IIS) sounds like an incredibly bad idea.


What I'm going to try next is to create a specific real windows account with limited privileges to run under.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get symlinks to work by going under the site, clicking authentication->Anonymous Authentication->Specific User and having the site run under a real windows account.  The account had NTFS permissions and user rights assignment to create links but was not an administrator.

The application pool can still run under application pool identity.

However, as I understand it, using the application pool identities are supposed to be the safer way to go.  I still wonder if there is a way to make symlinks work while using the app pool identity.